# CameraX works on Android Q but not on Android R

Tags: android-camerax, android-11

I am trying to create a custom camera app using CameraX by following the example from [Google Codelabs](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/camerax-getting-started/#0).

The tutorial specifically states:

```
We recommend using an AVD that is based on Android 11 or higher.
```

It is working fine with `API 29 (Android 10)` but it does not work with `API 30 (Android 10+)` and produces the following error:

```
2020-08-11 11:22:34.979 8607-8698/com.codelabs.camerax E/CameraCaptureSession: Session 0: Exception while stopping repeating: 
    android.hardware.camera2.CameraAccessException: CAMERA_ERROR (3): cancelRequest:459: Camera 0: Error clearing streaming request: Function not implemented (-38)
        at android.hardware.camera2.CameraManager.throwAsPublicException(CameraManager.java:1009)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:99)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1263)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:578)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:789)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:245)
        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:110)
        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:230)
        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:172)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167)
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641)
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
     Caused by: android.os.ServiceSpecificException: cancelRequest:459: Camera 0: Error clearing streaming request: Function not implemented (-38) (code 10)
        at android.os.Parcel.createExceptionOrNull(Parcel.java:2387)
        at android.os.Parcel.createException(Parcel.java:2357)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2340)
        at android.os.Parcel.readException(Parcel.java:2282)
        at android.hardware.camera2.ICameraDeviceUser$Stub$Proxy.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUser.java:732)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.cancelRequest(ICameraDeviceUserWrapper.java:97)
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl.stopRepeating(CameraDeviceImpl.java:1263) 
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl.close(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:578) 
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraCaptureSessionImpl$2.onDisconnected(CameraCaptureSessionImpl.java:789) 
        at android.hardware.camera2.impl.CameraDeviceImpl$7.run(CameraDeviceImpl.java:245) 
        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$1.run(SequentialExecutor.java:110) 
        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.workOnQueue(SequentialExecutor.java:230) 
        at androidx.camera.core.impl.utils.executor.SequentialExecutor$QueueWorker.run(SequentialExecutor.java:172) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1167) 
        at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:641) 
        at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:923)
```

Dependency:

```
def camerax_version = "1.0.0-beta07"
// CameraX core library using camera2 implementation
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:$camerax_version"
// CameraX Lifecycle Library
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:$camerax_version"
// CameraX View class
implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.0.0-alpha14"

implementation "androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.2.0"
```

Comment: What is the version of your CameraX dependency?

Comment: @SaurabhThorat I have added the CameraX dependency: `1.0.0-beta07`.

Comment: Does it work for you in lower versions? I have a problem in all versions that the preview shrink to half of the screen does it happen with you?

Comment: @MohamedBenRomdhane It works in lower versions, and no, the preview does not shrink to half of the screen in my case.